# Настройка автоматического запуска job`a jenkins посредством webhook с jira!

Tags: jenkins, триггер, devops, jira

Использую плагин "JIRA Trigger Jenkisns" для самого Jenkins и webhook на стороне Jira, проблема в невозможности добавить webhook который ссылается на плагин Jenkisn`a.Получаю такую ошибку:"Неверный url"
[image: Скрин ошибки Jira]

В мануале плагина написано:

> 1.Go to JIRA > Cog > System > Advanced > WebHooks (Requires admin permission)
>     2.Create a new Webhook
>     3.Set URL to: ${Jenkins URL}/jira-trigger-webhook-receiver/ e.g. http://localhost:8080/jenkins/jira-trigger-webhook-receiver/
>     4.Enable issue updated event
>     5.If you are on JIRA Cloud, enable comment created event
>     6.Do not check Exclude body as this plugin requires the JSON to operate
>     7.Save!

Со времен публикации плагина и ридми к нему видимо много чего поменялось,Jira теперь не поддерживает 8080,только 80 && 443.На 80 категорически отказывает в применении настроек,https применяется но без ssl не функционирует.
Второй момент,при попытке запросить ${Jenkins URL}/jira-trigger-webhook-receiver/ через браузер получаю такой ответ от Jenkins:
[image: Jenkins screen]

Если попробовать нажать "Retry using POST" то запрос то появляется еще одна ошибка!
Что я делаю не так,как мне правильно добавить рабочий webhook?

Answer (score 0):

Взаимосвязь между Jira и Jenkins должна быть не через localhost, а через внутренний ip-адрес с открытым портом.

Посмотрите настройки безопасности Jira, откройте внутренний ip / порт экземпляра Jenkins, чтобы они смогли подключиться друг к другу.